# GoLang Mocking CSV Rest Response

Tags: unit-testing, go

I am trying to unit test an API which returns a CSV response. I am used to testing APIs that return Json response by doing something like this :

```
resBody := `{"access_token": "token","instance_url": "url","id": "id","token_type": "Bearer"}`
r := ioutil.NopCloser(bytes.NewReader([]byte(resBody)))

clientMock.GetMock = func(url string) (*http.Response, error) {
        return &http.Response{
            StatusCode: 200,
            Body:       r,
        }, nil
    }
```

Here, the resBody is my mocked Json response, however unable to figure out what would be an equivalent response structure for testing APIs that return csv response.

Answer (score 2):

Never mind, able to figure it out now.
Below can be used to mock CSV response :

```
resBody := `"access_token","instance_url","id","token_type"` + "\n" + `"token","url","id","Bearer"`
r := ioutil.NopCloser(bytes.NewReader([]byte(resBody)))

clientMock.GetMock = func(url string) (*http.Response, error) {
        return &http.Response{
            StatusCode: 200,
            Body:       r,
        }, nil
    }
```